# Is it possible to create Azure Data Factory Data Flows via code?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm new to Azure Data Factory, and currently reading through [this page on the Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-create). I see that you can use the ADF .NET SDK to do a number of operations through .NET. When I got to the Data Flow section, I saw mention of the Data Factory UI, and

> without any coding required.

Is there a way to create Data Flows using the ADF .NET SDK? I couldn't immediately find anything on a way that makes use of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/data-flows/create-or-update

for a pipeline, it seems that you can also use existing sdk:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-pipeline

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api

Comment: ADF SDKs support generating pipelines and dataflows programmatically. For data flows, the key is to generate the data flow script (can be found using the script button in the UI) and send that into the dataflow create method.